# "Greatest lower bound function"

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, supremum-and-infimum

If $f $ is a function continuous at $c, h $ is positive and $m$ is a function defined as $ m(h)=\inf \{ f(x):  x \in [c,c+h] \}$ ,   how can I prove that the limit of $ m $ as $ h $ approaches $ 0 $ is $ f(c)$ ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! To attract answers to your question, please add some context and background information.  For example, where did you encounter this problem (e.g. a book, class)?  Please also show your attempt; seeing your work helps us help you.  If this is homework, please [read this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353).  Also, we use $\LaTeX$ to format mathematics here. I've edited your question to use it; for more information, please see [this post on Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/23353)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint  : $\lim_{h \to 0}m(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}\inf \{ f(x):  x \in [c,c+h] \}=\inf \lim_{h \to 0}\{ f(x):  x \in [c,c+h] \}$(since $f$ is continuous )

Comment: Useful information. Thank you

Comment: Your are welcome, but the @kobe's answer is complete and nice you can write it.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous at $c$, given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$, $x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta)$ implies $f(x) \in (f(c) - \varepsilon, f(c) + \epsilon)$. Let $h$ be a real number such that $0 < h < \delta$. Since $f(x) > f(c) - \varepsilon$ for all $x \in [c,c+h]$, $m(h) \ge f(c) - \varepsilon$. Also, $m(h) \le f(x) < f(c) + \varepsilon$ for all $x \in [c,c+h]$. Thus $|m(h) - f(c)| \le \varepsilon$ whenever $0 < h < \delta$. Consequently, $\lim_{h\to 0} m(h) = f(c)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt answer

Comment: It was really helpful. Thanks